# Output page and session page state

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, webforms, outputcache

I want to add outputcache to my ASP.NET website. However, there is some code behind that changes some buttons and content based on whether the user is logged in or not. I am afraid that if I use it, it might cache the page with the code for a logged in user. Is this how it works, or whether I have to configure something so it will work with sessions?

Comment: Which techno are you using ASP.Net WebForms or ASP.Net MVC ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound webforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following changes:

Add `VaryByCustom` attribute and set its value to User in your `OutputCache` directive like this :

```
<%@ OutputCache VaryByCustom="User" .... %>
```

Then in your **Global.asax** file you need to override `GetVaryByCustomString` method like this :

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    if (custom.Equals("User", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Return the user name/login as a value that will invalidate cache per authenticated user. 
        return context.User.Identity.Name;
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

Based on your comments below to this anwser, you say you're using Session variable to check if user is logged in or not. Let me tell you that is not the best practices to manage authentication like that.

Any way the solution to invalidate cache depending on a session value is doing this :

```
<%@ OutputCache VaryByCustom="Session" .... %>
```

Again `VaryByCustom` can be any `string` value you want by giving it a meaning `string` is really good and let the future devs or you to know what you was doing.

Then override

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    if (custom.Equals("Session", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // make sure that the session value is convertible to string
        return (string)context.Session["Here you put your session Id"];
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

That is all you need to do. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what it does? What is the 'User' means, does it some hint for the output cache to do something related to the session?

Comment: User can be any string that relate to the cache. Here I need to invalidate the cache per authenticated user. Then I use the string "User" (that can be anything) to identify the cache parameter VaryByCustom. This value is passed to the overriden method `GetVaryByCustomString` in Global.axax. In that method I tell the cache to check if the user has changed.

Comment: Is there an option to serve non cache page for logged in user. I don't use the build in ASP.NET login, I implemented my own, and set a session variable to check if the user is logged in or not?

Comment: Is there a way to tell output cache to not cache the page for logged in users at all? (thanks a lot!)

Comment: Yep. Just return a ramdom string for each logged user then. Just do this `return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` Still not a good practice ;-)